# How to bind opaque types with Ctypes

Tags: ocaml, ctypes

I'm writing an OCaml binding for Quartz Event Services[1].

There are cases where I need to bind opaque types like in this code:

```
typedef CGEventRef  _Nullable (*CGEventTapCallBack)(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *userInfo);
```

Here, `CGEventRef` is a pointer on a `__CGEvent` structure on which I know nothing. I manipulate this type only through its interface.

How can I bind such opaque types using Ctypes?

**Links**

1. https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1658572-quartz_event_services?language=objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I'm treating pointers on opaque types as void pointers.

```
type machport_ref = unit ptr
let machport_ref = ptr void

type event_ref = unit ptr
let event_ref = ptr void
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better approach, but that's what I've used in the past.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not deference the pointer you can handle it as a c_void_p.

Pointers are just memory addresses, it does not matter if it is called CGEventRef or SomeOtherRandomPointer or just a simple void pointer, it only takes the memory address as a argument.